# [react-native][Xcode 13.1] unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=4096m' Mac M1 (Monterey)

Tags: java, react-native

I've freshly installed `Mac Monterey OS` with latest version of Java `JDK 17` & `XCode 13.1`

When I run `npm run android` to build my project I get below error.

[image]

```
unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=4096m' 
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending 2hrs on this issue I removed the Java `JDK 17` and installed `jdk-15.0.2` because in `Big Sur` i was using this version itself & this fixed the problem and the project build was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. The fix in my case was to **refer to a correct version of JDK**. My Android Studio is 64-bit (on Windows you can see it in task manager as studio64.exe) while it was referring to 32-bit JDK. To check it go to `File > Other Settings > Default Project Structure > JDK location` and check the path. Select the correct version of JDK. If you don't have a 64-bit JDK then download and install it.